# Uncaught ReferenceError: createProduct is not defined at HTMLFormElement.onreset

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `form` which works fine with the below code. My problem is that I want the `var database = []` to be in a parent `function`, outside the `function createProduct`. 
But, when I use a parent `function` I get the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: createProduct is not defined at
>   HTMLFormElement.onreset

```js
 function createProduct(form){
  var json = {
              "name":    form.name.value,
              "code":    form.code.value,
          };

  var getProduct = JSON.stringify(json);
  var jsProduct  = JSON.parse(getProduct);
  createDatabase(jsProduct);

  function createDatabase(jsProduct){
     var database = [];
     database.push(jsProduct);
     return;
   } 
   
   return;
 }
```

```html
<form  onreset="return createProduct(this);">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name...">

    <label for="code">Code</label>
    <input type="text" id="code" name="code" placeholder="Code..."> 
</form>
```

Comment: can you include whole form?

Comment: no I couldn't. I tried and the error occurs

Comment: is your script placed at the beginning of your file? Because it says createProduct is not defined meaning that when your onreset is being called your function has not been created yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var database = [];

function createProduct(form){
  var json = {
              "name":    form.name.value,
              "code":    form.code.value,
          };

  var getProduct = JSON.stringify(json);
  var jsProduct  = JSON.parse(getProduct);
  createDatabase(jsProduct);
  //Or you can directly push it, instead of calling createDatabase, uncomment below line
//database.push(jsProduct);
 }
 
function createDatabase(jsProduct){
  database.push(jsProduct);
}
```